# Photoshop-like web apps

Tags: webapp-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What online image editing / image manipulation web applications exist?  Features?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/276/what-online-image-editing-image-manipulation-web-applications-exist-features)

What are some good (if any) web app alternatives to Photoshop?

<sub>I am aware of [SketchPad](http://mugtug.com/sketchpad/)/[DarkRoom](http://mugtug.com/darkroom/), [Aviary](http://aviary.com/dashboard) and [Thumba](http://www.thumba.net/), but of those only Aviary suite comes close, and even it is lacking a lot of essential effects (or I don't know where those are).</sub>

Comment: If it's not mentioned in any of the other related questions, the answer might just be: No...

Comment: lol, it's possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Photoshop.com](http://photoshop.com)

[Pixlr](http://pixlr.com)

[Picnik](http://picnik.com)

Answer (score 0):

I think Aviary.com is a pretty good one, and one of the first to market.  Picnik is getting some heat right now and Yahoo/Flickr seem to stand by it.  But I don't think you are going to get anywhere near the power of a desktop app.  Some of other popular sites not mentioned include Splashup.com and Sumopaint.com.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say [Pixlr](http://pixlr.com/) is one of the best I've used. You can even jump straight to http://pixlr.com/express/ and start using it without registering or other faff.